# protractor showing wrong chromedriver version and unable to run e2e tests

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working with an angular2 web application were we have setup protractor for e2e testing but my all tests are keep failing for some ambiguous error. 
The error is get is

```
× Full amount can be tendered to card via scanning the device
  - Failed: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
  - Failed: unknown error: cannot get automation extension
from unknown error: page could not be found: chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/_generated_background_page.html
 (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362(5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

My environment is windows 10, node version is 6.9.1, npm version is 3.8.6, chrome version is 59.xx, chromedriver version is 2.30 but don't know why its showing 2.26 in console along with error. I've tried to update it through npm install chromedriver (both locally and global) and it shows that 2.30 is installed but when I try to run protractor its show chromedriver=2.26.436362 (as you can see in output). I've tried many solution found on internet but nothing worked for me (included upgrading chrome to latest version + chromedriver to latest version, downgrading chrome to 58 and chromedriver to 2.28 etc).

Anything I'm missing in setting up my environment ? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

*******UPDATE*******

I've upgraded chromedriver version to 2.30 and now started getting different error, it doesn't even start now, error is following

```
e2e/app/framework/element-functions.ts(43,29): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
e2e/app/framework/wait-functions.ts(45,18): error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<{}> | Condition<{}> | ((driver: WebDriver) => {})'.
Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(driver: WebDriver) => {}'.
Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(driver: WebDriver): {}'
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/angular_wait_barrier.d.ts(43,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/blockingproxy.d.ts(40,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(11,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(18,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/client.d.ts(19,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/highlight_delay_barrier.d.ts(17,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(14,47): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(21,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(29,56): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/simple_webdriver_client.d.ts(37,52): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/webdriver_proxy.d.ts(14,90): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/webdriver_proxy.d.ts(23,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(31,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(48,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(62,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(76,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
node_modules/protractor/built/plugins.d.ts(94,55): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've seen this. Webdriver-manager gets confused, and grabs the wrong version. To fix, run this on *both* local (node_modules) and global (if you have it there too) Protractor installs.

1. `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager clean // removes all older versions`
2. `node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update // get the latest`

Comment: Thanks @Brine for your response, yes I was able to update to latest version of chromedriver as you said but now I'm started getting different error. It doesn't even start now. I'm updating question now with latest error. Kindly see if you can suggest some solution for this.

Comment: That's a different issue, and you should create a new question for it. Otherwise it pollutes _this_ question.